# Admob Android Bonus Ad Issue

Tags: android, admob

I have a roulette that you can spin if you watch a bonus ad, the problem I have is that if the user closes the advertisement, hits SKIP and does not wait all the time, the roulette still spins, the idea is that rotate only if user sees all advertising

I leave the code to see why this happens

```
    b_anuncio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    
    
                    if (rewardedAd != null) {
    
    
    
                        rewardedAd.show(
                                getActivity(),
                                new OnUserEarnedRewardListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem rewardItem) {
    
    
                                    }
    
                                });
    
                    }
    
    
                    assert rewardedAd != null;
                    rewardedAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                            // Called when ad is shown.
    
    
                        }
    
                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                            // Called when ad fails to show.
    
                        }
    
                        @Override
                        public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                            // Called when ad is dismissed.
                            // Set the ad reference to null so you don't show the ad a second time.
    
                            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
    
                                    giraruleta();
                                    createAndLoadRewardedAd();
    
                                }
                            }, 1000);
    
                            rewardedAd = null;
    
                        }
                    });
                }
    
    
            });
    
    
            imageRoulette.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roulette_10));
}
```

Comment: instead of calling giraruleta onAdDismissedFullScreenContent. Call it in OnUserEarnedRewardListener  https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/OnUserEarnedRewardListener

Comment: Hi Amod, If I put it there, it happens that while the Video is being watched, the roulette wheel spins. I do not know how to make it rotate, only when the time is up and the user closes the advertisement